# Replace double quotes with single using angular-translate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using `angular-translate` for translating English to French but the issue is it converts single quote to double quote. I want to replace translated double quotes with single quote. I have a filter but its not applying on translated text.

Code snippet:

```
<div class="no-text" ng-if="question.length == 0" translate="msg.site_is_not_applicable" translate-default="This site is not applicable"></div>
```

e.g. msg.site_is_not_applicable(EN) = This site is not applicable

After translated in French = le site n''est pas applicable

Want to replace double quoted with single quote. Can someone help how I can do this using angular-translate.js.

```
<div class="no-text" ng-if="question.length == 0" translate="msg.site_is_not_applicable | quoteSingle" translate-default="This site is not applicable"></div>
```

filter.js

```
app.module('app.filters', []).filter('quoteSingle', function() {
   return function(text) {
    return text.replace(/"/g, "'");
   };
});
```

Comment: The `app.module()` seems odd. You're writing that for brevity of the example?
This should probably be `app.module('yourapp')...`. and `'quoteSingle` is missing the closing `'`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `translate` directive make use of `translate` filter. And then you can chain multiple filters on same binding property. So you can add your custom filter after translate filter. Your template code can be:

```
<div class="no-text" ng-if="question.length == 0"> 
 {{msg.site_is_not_applicable | translate | quoteSingle}}
</div>
```

[**Plunker Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/p5Ae2sqq5l5KybByMNYr?p=preview)